# Paypal redirect page after payment process

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I want to display a template page after the payment process with paypal.
This is the code of the paypal button referring to the redirect page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://site.mysite.local:83/buyOk">


<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> //return URL using POST method
```

I've created a template php file called `buy_process_ok.html.php` and in the controller the function:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/buyOk")
     */

    public function buyProcessOkAction() {

        return $this->renderView('UserBundle:Account:buy_process_ok.html.php');

    }
```

At the end of the payment process i get this error:

```
No route found for "POST /buyOk"
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache since creating the route? Also you aren't returning anything from your controller so it would kick up an error about expecting a `Response` object so you will need to add `return $this->renderView.....`.

Comment: The `return` was there, I've edited the original post. I've added the route method allowing POST, but nothing changes, same error.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Is the route nested or is there a prefix? What does the dump of your `debug:router` look like?

Comment: Cache cleared. In `debug:router` I have the following line: `user_account_buyprocessok                         GET|POST ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/user/user/buyOk `

Comment: That would be why your link isn't working. There is no route at `/buyOk`. Your actual path would be something like `/en/user/user/buyOk`. You can generate the url using `{{ url('user_account_buyprocessok', {'locale': your_locale }) }}` rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: can you show the full controller?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan This is the definition of the controller: `/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/user")
 */
class AccountController extends Controller
{...`

Comment: @qooplmao That means that if I put this link in the redirect link : (http://site.mysite.local:83/en/user/user/buyOk) all should work? I've tried but nothing. Sorry if I don't get it

Comment: Does it show an error or is it a blank page?

Comment: @qooplmao same error as before, No route found for "POST /buyOk". This is the link in the button: ` <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://site.mysite.local:83/en/user/user/buyOk">
`

Comment: It looks like your redirect isn't actually going to the right page (hence the `POST /buyOK` rather than `POST /en/user/user/buyOk`). What happens if you just go to that link in your browser?

Comment: with the `renderView` I get an error saying the controller must return a response. Now I'm using `$this->render` and I get the template diplayed correctly

Comment: But If I follow the entire payment process, the template isn't rendered